# About definition of endomorphism on vectos space

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

"let $ f $ be a  homomorphism between two vector spaces $V$ and $W$, $f$ is endomorphism on $V$ if $im(f) \subseteq V$"

is correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $V$ a subspace of $W$? If not, I don't see how $\operatorname{im}(f)$ could be a subset of $V$.

Comment: Endomorphism is any map $f:V\to V$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, mmm ok.. therefore if V a subspace of W the definition is correct?

Comment: @Artem You mean certainly any *linear* map.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't actually make sense unless we require $V$ to be a subspace of $W$. Normally we define an endomorphism to be a map from $V$ to $V$ with certain properties, specifically so that we don't have to worry about such technicalities.

But this definition is correct (assuming that by "homomorphism," you mean $\Bbb{F}$-linear map, where $\Bbb{F}$ is the underlying field) whenever $V$ is a subspace of $W$.